# mysql select from column if not equal 0, else select from another column

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have this query

```
            SELECT 
                products.*, colors.name AS colorName, makes.name AS makeName, genders.name AS genderName,
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT categories.name ORDER BY categories.name) AS distCategories, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT subcategories.name ORDER BY subcategories.name) AS distSubcategories, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT makes.name ORDER BY makes.name) AS distMakes, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT products_availability.size ORDER BY products_availability.size) AS distSizes 
            FROM products 
                LEFT JOIN colors ON products.color = colors.id 
                LEFT JOIN makes ON products.make = makes.id 
                LEFT JOIN genders ON products.gender = genders.id 
                LEFT JOIN products_and_categories ON products_and_categories.product = products.id 
                LEFT JOIN products_and_subcategories ON products_and_subcategories.product = products.id 
                LEFT JOIN products_availability ON products_availability.product = products.id 
                LEFT JOIN categories ON products_and_categories.category = categories.id 
                LEFT JOIN subcategories ON products_and_subcategories.subcategory = subcategories.id 
            WHERE products.gender IN(5, 6, 7) AND products.type = 5 AND $where 
            GROUP BY(products.id)
            ORDER BY products.id ASC
```

and I want to be able to select some products based on their prices.

If the column `sale_price` is NOT 0, then I want to say `WHERE sale_price <= :value`, but if the `sale_price` is 0 I want to say `WHERE price <= :value`.

Basically when filtering results by price, I don't want to take in consideration the original price if the product is on sale and has a `sale_price`, otherwise, if it's not on sale I will perform the query on the `price` column.

I tried with `CASE`

```
$where = 'CASE WHEN products.sale_price > 0 THEN products.sale_price <= : value WHEN products.sale_price = 0 THEN products.price <= : value ';
```

but this does not work.

Also note that the default value of the column is `0` being a `DIGIT` and not `NULL`.

Any help on how to construct the query will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With few modifications in your CASE statement, I guess you can make it work. Try something like:

```
SELECT 
products.*, 
colors.name AS colorName, 
makes.name AS makeName,  
genders.name AS genderName,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT categories.name ORDER BY categories.name) AS distCategories, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT subcategories.name ORDER BY subcategories.name) AS distSubcategories, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT makes.name ORDER BY makes.name) AS distMakes, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT products_availability.size ORDER BY products_availability.size) AS distSizes 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN colors ON products.color = colors.id 
LEFT JOIN makes ON products.make = makes.id 
LEFT JOIN genders ON products.gender = genders.id 
LEFT JOIN products_and_categories ON products_and_categories.product = products.id 
LEFT JOIN products_and_subcategories ON products_and_subcategories.product = products.id 
LEFT JOIN products_availability ON products_availability.product = products.id 
LEFT JOIN categories ON products_and_categories.category = categories.id 
LEFT JOIN subcategories ON products_and_subcategories.subcategory = subcategories.id 
WHERE products.sale_price = CASE WHEN products.sale_price > 0 
THEN products.sale_price <=  value ELSE products.price <=  value END
AND products.gender IN(5, 6, 7) 
AND products.type = 5 
GROUP BY(products.id)
ORDER BY products.id ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, unfortunately I get a syntax error near `'ELSE products.price <= END AND products.gender IN(2, 4) AND products.type...'`. I hardcoded some values and copied/pasted the query as you wrote it.

Comment: Some logic looks wrong here. In your WHERE clause you are trying to assign some values to two different variables. Can we not put the CASE inside the SELECT itself and keep the WHERE clause free from it?

Comment: I don't need to use the `CASE`, it was just a method I found searching for this particular problem. In the end I think I got it, now the `WHERE` regarding the price is like this `WHERE ((products.sale_price <= :value AND products.sale_price > 0) OR products.price <= :value)`. `:value` is the same variable which will be bind to the query with pdo. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: Yeah..this looks a simpler solution. :)